# Async functionality strange behaviour in Spring boot application running on Azure ubuntu 18.04 agent

Tags: spring-boot, azure, asynchronous, kubernetes, ubuntu-18.04

I have a question about using **async functionality** in a **Spring Boot application in an Azure environment**.

**NB Note: the issue doesn't occur running the application locally, only when I run it on an Azure ubuntu-18.04 agent**

I have a function I am executing asynchronously, in which I also print out the thread that is executing:

```
@Async
public void asyncFunction() {
    log.info("Executing thread {}", Thread.currentThread().getName())

    // Rest of function
}
```

I've added @EnableAsync to my application class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAsync
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

I don't configure the async functionality in any other way.

When the application starts up I can also see that **ThreadPoolTaskExecutor** is used as the task executor.

```
2022-05-23 11:26:30.494 [] [] [] [] -- INFO  -- o.s.s.c.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor -- Initializing ExecutorService 'threadPoolTaskExecutor'
```

(Which is contrary to what some sources say is used as the default - the default is SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor)

**The application is running in a kubernetes environment and is running on an Azure ubuntu 18.04 agent.**

**Problem/confusing part:**

I'm getting the following output:

```
Executing thread task-1
Executing thread task-2
Executing thread task-3
Executing thread task-4
Executing thread task-5
Executing thread task-6
Executing thread task-7
Executing thread task-8
```

The thread number is always incremented (This number has gone into the thousands without ever re-using a thread).

I was expecting output similar to this:

```
Executing thread task-1
Executing thread task-2
Executing thread task-1
Executing thread task-2
Executing thread task-3
Executing thread task-1
Executing thread task-2
```

I'm expecting thread re-use (e.g. thread 1 is re-used when it is available again), but it doesn't seem to happen?
I can confirm that my function runs to completion, so to my understanding the threads should be released once the function completes?
If I understand correctly the default lifespan for a thread is 60 seconds, but even after that threads aren't re-used.

I've played around with configuration like this:

```
@Override
@Bean(name = "threadPoolTaskExecutor")
public Executor getAsyncExecutor() {
    ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    executor.setCorePoolSize(20);
    executor.setMaxPoolSize(1000);
    executor.setWaitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown(true);
    executor.setThreadNamePrefix("task-");
    return executor;
}
```

But only when it reaches 20 threads does it use thread 1 again.

**So my questions are:**

- Why aren't my threads getting re-used?
- My async function completes, should that not release my threads for re-use?
- Could the issue be with how my Azure agent is configured?

**NB Note: the issue doesn't occur running the application locally, only when I run it on the Azure ubuntu-18.04 agent**

Maybe I'm misunderstanding something about async and Azure agent configurations (I'm not really a devops engineer), but I'm struggling to find enough information.

Thanks you!

Comment: You have a pool of 20 threads (minimum), 1 of those threads is being used for execution, which depends on the JVM implementation. Some use /track free threads, others use round-robin etc.

Comment: What JVM are you using? Please show the kubernetes manifest as well